# What is the easiest way to pass an element as first argument to event handlers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, bind, this

I know that having the value of `this` being changed to the element receiving the event in event handling functions is pretty useful. However, I'd like to make my functions always be called in my application context, and not in an element context.  This way, I can use them as event handlers and in other ways such as in `setTimeout` calls.

So, code like this:

```
window.app = (function () {
    var that = {
        millerTime: function () {},
        changeEl: function (el) {
            el = el || this;
            // rest of code...
            that.millerTime();
        }
    };
    return that;
}());
```

could just be like this:

```
window.app = (function () {
    return {
        millerTime: function () {},
        changeEl: function (el) {
            // rest of code...
            this.millerTime();
        }
    };
}());
```

The first way just looks confusing to me.  Is there a good easy way to pass the element receiving the event as the first argument (preferably a jQuery-wrapped element) to my event handling function and call within the context of `app`?  Let's say I bind a bunch of event handlers using jQuery.  I don't want to have to include anonymous functions all the time:

```
$('body').on('click', function (event) {
    app.changeEl.call(app, $(this), event);  // would be nice to get event too
});
```

I need a single function that will take care of this all for me.  At this point I feel like there's no getting around passing an anonymous function, but I just want to see if someone might have a solution.

My attempt at it:

```
function overrideContext (event, fn) {
   if (!(this instanceof HTMLElement) ||
         typeof event === 'undefined'
   ) {
       return overrideContext;
   }

   // at this point we know jQuery called this function // ??
   var el = $(this);

   fn.call(app, el, event);
}

$('body').on('click', overrideContext(undefined, app.changeEl));
```

**EDIT:**
Using `Function.prototype.bind` (which I am new to), I still can't get the element:

```
window.app = (function () {
    return {
         millerTime: function () {},
         changeEl: function (el) {
            // rest of code...
            console.log(this); // app
            this.millerTime();
         }
    };
}());

function overrideContext (evt, fn) {
    var el = $(this); // $(Window)
    console.log(arguments); // [undefined, app.changeEl, p.Event] 
    fn.call(app, el, event);
}

$('body').on('click', overrideContext.bind(null, undefined, app.changeEl));
```

Using `$('body').on('click', overrideContext.bind(app.changeEl));` instead, `this` points to my `app.changeEl` function and my arguments length is 1 and contains only `p.Event`.  I still can't get the element in either instance.

Comment: look at `$.proxy`  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/ which allows you to change context of handlers

Comment: Looking at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/, `$.proxy` doesn't seem like it allows you to pass the element.  I need some sort of late binding.  I would like to have my cake and eat it too.

Comment: google some use case demos/tutorials... can do more than you think

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Function.prototype.bind`.

```
$('body').on('click', overrideContext.bind(null, undefined, app.changeEl));
```

You could also pass in the actual `element` as the context for the method

```
$('body').on('click', overrideContext.bind(app.changeEl));
```

Comment: OK, so I am new to `Function.prototype.bind`, and I think that learning to use it on event handlers is a terrible introduction.  With either of your statements I still could not get the clicked element to be in the arguments.  I edited my question with the results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your mistake is trying to control which arguments will be passed to the event handler. If you really, really want that, you'd have to create your own event handling utilities, like jQuery does, and call the handlers manually, passing whatever you want as parameters.

But, do you really need that? If you rely on regular handlers attached with `addEventListener`, or handlers attached with one of the various methods available in jQuery, you'll always get the `event` object as the first parameter. And the element that triggered the event will always be available at `event.target`.

Considering that, you can just use `Function.prototype.bind`, as jAndy suggested, to set `this` to any value you want.